# comparing multi dimension arrays

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, compare

I have 2 images and each is partial of a complete image, and the 2 combined could create the complete image.

However there is overlap on the 2 images, and I am trying to create a program that will find where the top row of image2 meets whichever row of pixels in image 1.
I created a for loop to gather each row of pixels per image in an array.

this is my code:

```
int row = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < imageArray1.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < imageArray1[i].length; j++) {
            if (imageArray1[i][j] == (imageArray2[0][0])) {
                row = imageArray1[i][j];
            }
        }

    }
```

the problem is I am pretty sure I am only gathering a with the individual pixel that is top left of the second image, rather than the whole row.
Any ideas how to get around this?
new to java

Comment: are the first row of image2 being totally inside image1, or it is going to be a partial overlap? and what is the type of imageArray1 and 2? are each element represnting one pixel? (coz that's weird that you write `row=imageArray1[i][j]` which seems you are assigning a "pixel" to "row index"

Comment: Hey Siue, have you got a good answer?

Comment: Yes bond. What I did was actually just take the first pixel of a row from the first picture and checked it against the first pixel of a row on the second. If they matched it move over one pixel in each row. If it got to the end of the row that was the correct row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cross check each rows in image1 against each rows in image2. Therefore, **3 levels of looping**: **1)** loop through the rows in image1 **2)** loop through the rows in image2 **3)** loop through the columns in the current row in image1 and image2 to decide if they are overlapping

```
    int overlappingRowInImage1 = 0;
    int overlappingRowInImage2 = 0;
    int[][] imageArray1 = null;
    int[][] imageArray2 = null;
    // loop through the rows in the first image
    for (int row1 = 0; row1 < imageArray1.length; row1++) {
        boolean foundIdenticalRow = false;
        // loop through the rows in the second image
        for (int row2 = 0; row2 < imageArray2.length; row2++) {
            foundIdenticalRow = true;
            // two rows are identical if each column in both rows are the same
            for (int col = 0; col < imageArray1[row1].length; col++) {
                if (imageArray1[row1][col] != (imageArray2[row2][col])) {
                    foundIdenticalRow = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (foundIdenticalRow) {
                overlappingRowInImage1 = row1;
                overlappingRowInImage2 = row2;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundIdenticalRow) {
            System.out.println("Row " + overlappingRowInImage1 + " in image 1 is overlapping with Row " +
                    overlappingRowInImage2 + " in image 2");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It gives me row 0 as the answer every time, hmmmm

Comment: @SIUE_KYLE can you share your test data

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the `imageArray2[0][0]` so it's always comparing with the first index of `imageArray2` only. You need to iterate your `imageArray2` along with `imageArray1` for full comparison. For this I would suggest you to use a nested for loop for `imageArray2`.

Comment: hmmm i can think of doing another if statement that compares to the image2[0][1] but thats still comparng only the first pixel of image1 and now the entire row...

Comment: add another for statement and use the variable of that loop to iterate for second image array